# Interface Builder: Why is my UIView transparent?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, interface-builder

I have a random `UIView` with a background color of black and alpha set to 1.0. I have a `UIImageView` behind it displaying a test screenshot. Interface Builder shows the black `UIView` to be transparent however. Why?

[image]

Using Xcode 6.2 because 6.3 crashes on start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually noticed this earlier today as well. Turns out it's just something Xcode does to help you see what's behind that particular view while building the UI in Interface Builder. If you compile the app and run it in the simulator/on a device, you'll see that it does indeed have an `alpha` of `1.0`.

Comment: That's annoying. I was playing with the colors to match the color with the images.